# How to type a string that should match an i18next translation key that matches a string and not a nested object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

I want to declare `i18next` translation keys as property values in an object and type it as a `Record<string, SomeType>` in a way that it only accepts values that are valid `i18next` translation keys (only leafs as I don't want it to accept keys for sections that have nested keys so that the result is always a string when I pass the key to `t()`).

I have this code (using `i18next` 22.4 and `react-i18next` 12.2)

```js
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import type { TFuncKey } from 'i18next';

// A map of paths to translation keys
// I want TS to complain here if I try to use a string that
// doesn't match a translation key matching a string.
// This below works otherwise but `TFuncKey` is a bit too loose type as
// it also accepts e.g. 'Navigation` which results in an object, not a string.
const pageTitles: Record<string, TFuncKey> = {
  '/': 'Navigation.home', // note: plain string values here, not calling `t()`
  '/about': 'Navigation.about',
  '/other': 'Navigation.other',
};


function useTitle(path: string): string {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return pageTitles[path] ? t(pageTitles[path]) : t('ErrorMessages.error');
  // The previous line currently gives a TS error because t(pageTitles[path]) may
  // return an object (not matching the return type of string in this method)
}
```

I can workaround the error by using `t(pageTitles[path]) as string` but then it might break at runtime as the `TFuncKey` type is a bit too loose and I can accidentally pass a value like `''Navigation''` which won't result in a string when passed to `t()`.

If I have the map object inlined like this then the code works as intended:

```js
function useTitle(path: string): string {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return {
    '/': t('Navigation.home'), // note: calling `t()` here directly
    '/about': t('Navigation.about'),
    '/other': t('Navigation.other'),
  }[path] ?? t('ErrorMessages.error');
}
```

but I'd like to refactor the map to be declared elsewhere (outside this React hook) where I can't use `useTranslation()` as my actual code is a bit more complex (and has more routes) than the example here. So if possible I'd like to have it more like in the first example if it's possible to fix the typings so that TS is satisfied with it.

I'm not sure if I can use the generics of `TFuncKey` or some other type from `i18next` to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem will be solved just by upgrading to `i18next` 23.x.

The type `TFuncKey` will need to be replaced with `ParseKeys` as mentioned in the [migration guide](https://www.i18next.com/misc/migration-guide#more-information-features-and-breaking-changes) (the type was renamed).

I was originally using using `i18next 22.4` (and `react-i18next` 12.2) but after upgrading to `i18next` 23.4 (and `react-i18next` 13.0) the code above works just as intended as it will complain if trying to use for example `'Navigation'` as a value in the `pageTitles` object.

This is due to the new redesigned types in `i18next` 23 and the `returnObjects` option which seems to globally default to `false` (may also be set explicitly as an option per call of `t()`).

Answer (score 0):

make pageTitles const.

```js
const pageTitles = {
  '/': 'Navigation.home',
  '/about': 'Navigation.about',
  '/other': 'Navigation.other',
} as const;
```

Comment: With your example TS would not give any errors related to the translation keys in place where the `pageTitles` is defined (as it is not typed) but only where used (e.g. in `useTitle`) which would not be as easy to work with when editing `pageTitles`.

Nice suggestion though, but it doesn't answer my main question (see title and first paragraph) and I just figured out that I can get a better solution just by upgrading to latest version of `i18next` while keeping the explicit typing of `pageTitles` (see the answer I just posted).